# Oracle Context Index - finding unsynchronised records

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, index-tuning

Context indexes can be update with the procedure:

```
Ctx_Ddl.Sync_Index (index_name);
```

But what exactly is synchronised by this function?  How does Oracle know what is unsynchronised (i.e. how does it track the delta between what's in the index and what's in the underlying data)?  And can I as a DBA view this delta?

Moreover, am I able to exert some control over what data is synchronised?  Can I stop it from synchronising certain data within the index?

Comment: Asking about Oracle internals is not likely to get you a good answer unless you tell us what problem you are trying to solve

Comment: This might be relevant for [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298864/speed-up-oracle-text-indexing-or-let-the-indexer-work-only-on-low-load-times) even though it was very old post discussion about syncing index